# Button/JPanel grids don't appear correctly

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, awt, jbutton

I have 3 classes.
I want to create a 3x3 array grid of `JPanel`.
Each `JPanel` contains a 3x3 array grid of `JButton`s. (it will be a total of 81 `JButton` like a Sudoku).

The Problem is that when I execute my program, it doesn't show up all the `JPanel`s, only a few `JPanel`s (with their `JButton`s) appears...

Here's the Code of my 3 classes, I can't find where's the problem...

`Main` class:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {

    public static Griglia g[][] = new Griglia[3][3];

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame f = new JFrame();


        Listener lis = new Listener();

        for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
        {
            for(int ii=0; ii<3; ii++)
            {
                g[i][ii]=new Griglia();
                g[i][ii].setLocation(i*155,ii*155);
                g[i][ii].repaint();
                g[i][ii].addMouseListener(lis);
                f.add(g[i][ii]);
                g[i][ii].setVisible(true);
                g[i][ii].repaint();

                f.repaint();

            }
        }

        f.setSize(470,500);

        f.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

`Griglia` class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Griglia extends JPanel{

    Casella c[][] = new Casella[3][3];
    int flag=0;

    public Griglia(){
        this.setSize(150,150);
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setBackground(Color.black);

        for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
        {
            for(int ii=0; ii<3; ii++)
            {
                c[i][ii]=new Casella();
                c[i][ii].setLocation(i*50, ii*50);
                c[i][ii].repaint();
                this.add(c[i][ii]);
                this.repaint();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`Casella` class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class Casella extends JButton{

    int flag=0;

    public Casella(){
        this.setSize(50,50);
        this.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: Griglia Class -> used for JPanel Grid

Comment: Casella Class -> used for JButton Grid/array

Comment: Don't use a null layout. Use a panel with a GridLayout. Don't add comments to your question. Update the question so all the information is in one place. Swing components are visible by default. There is no need for setVisible(). Swing will paint the components when the frame is made visible. There is no need to use repaint().

Comment: `this.setLayout(null);` is primary issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The very basic issue with your code is a lack of understand into how the layout management API works.

For starters, `JFrame` uses a `BorderLayout` by default, meaning that, in your case, only the last component added will be displayed.

Trying to rely on `null` layouts is ill advised and will cause you no end of issues in the long run.

A better solution is to find one or more layout managers which help you achieve your solution, for example, `GridLayout`

Start by having a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) and [How to Use GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html)

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Main {

    public static Griglia g[][] = new Griglia[3][3];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    for (int ii = 0; ii < 3; ii++) {
                        g[i][ii] = new Griglia();
//                        g[i][ii].setLocation(i * 155, ii * 155);
//                g[i][ii].repaint();
//                g[i][ii].addMouseListener(lis);
                        frame.add(g[i][ii]);
//                g[i][ii].setVisible(true);
//                g[i][ii].repaint();

//                f.repaint();
                    }
                }

                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

    }

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public static class Griglia extends JPanel {

        Casella c[][] = new Casella[3][3];
        int flag = 0;

        public Griglia() {
//            this.setSize(150, 150);
//            this.setLayout(null);
            this.setBackground(Color.black);

            setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                for (int ii = 0; ii < 3; ii++) {
                    c[i][ii] = new Casella();
//                    c[i][ii].setLocation(i * 50, ii * 50);
//                    c[i][ii].repaint();
                    this.add(c[i][ii]);
//                    this.repaint();
                }
            }
        }
    }

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public static class Casella extends JButton {

        int flag = 0;

        public Casella() {
//            this.setSize(50, 50);
            this.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
//            this.setVisible(true);
        }

    }
}
```